# Zooming WebView with svg inside. SVG is pixelized if zoomed

Tags: android, svg, webview, zooming, pixel

```
public class TWVSVGMainActivity extends Activity {  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);     
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/003.svg");
}}
```

After zooming the SVG image it is pixelized.

I want to load the svg to WebView, and I want text from *.svg file not to be pixelized.

What have I missed?

Comment: Fixed on HTML side. There is some bug, if html page have only SVG - it will be pixelized if zoom. But, if HTML page contains at least one symbol - zooming will work fine.

Comment: Please specify your solution as a proper answer, not as a comment, and if it works for you, accept (your own) answer. It would be useful to provide some more details. What do you mean by "HTML page contains at least one symbol"? Thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue, he means you need to add a character, like a full stop or any letter into the HTML. You cannot just have the SVG image by itself or the image will be pixelated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to be able to zoom an SVG in a WebView and initially display it fully zoomed out:

```
setInitialScale(1);
WebSettings settings = getSettings();
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got my SVG File to display in the Jelly Bean WebView:

I included the SVG into an HTML document using the embed tag:

`<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="{{ svg_url }}" type="image/svg+xml"/>`

It was very important to include width and height attributes because otherwise the SVG appeared cut off in the Jelly Bean WebView.

I also had to include some random text in the HTML page, thanks to Chab (see above).  Something like this did the trick:

`<span style="color:White;">hidden</span>`

I also had to set the `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = yes">` tag in combination with `webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);` for the SVG to scale without cutting off part of the image.

Hope that helps